# php : convert serialized to array

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a form sending a post request to server . there is a hidden input in form containing a serialized string value :
`"menuItem[2]=null&menuItem[4]=2&menuItem[6]=4&menuItem[5]=2&menuItem[7]=null&menuItem[3]=null"`

I'm trying to convert this string to an array using php:
   `[ 2 => null, 4 => 2, 6 => 4 , ...]`

is there any neat way to do that?

Comment: why not use `.serializeArray()` ?

Comment: why not use `JSON` on both sides?

Comment: Im using a plugin (ilikenwf/nestedSortable )[https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable] that has a serialize method that produce above serialized string . so i cant use that

Comment: Why are you inserting that string in an input in the first place? WHy can't you just send the serialized data to server

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain more? how may i send POST  request without using a form?

Comment: jQuery `$.post(url, serializedData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str('menuItem[2]=null&menuItem[4]=2&menuItem[6]=4&menuItem[5]=2&menuItem[7]=null&menuItem[3]=null', $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Will result in:

```
array (
  'menuItem' => 
    array (
      2 => 'null',
      4 => '2',
      6 => '4',
      5 => '2',
      7 => 'null',
      3 => 'null',
  )
)
```